# Text looks fuzzy on the edges in a GIF or an image no matter what size I type them.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image: How it looks like]

Has anyone ever experienced this before me?

Comment: Yes: everyone who has ever typed text onto a raster computer screen. However, there are levels of fuzziness, and you can select several in Photoshop. Unfortunately your screen shot, overly large as it is, does not show the text rendering options that you used for this text.

Comment: Hey Suzanna! It's a little hard to tell what's going on with the info we have, can you include us a screen shot with the text selected and the Type palette opened up?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have text antialiasing set to none.

Try changing it to smooth (or any other for that matter).

[image]